# Difference between different integer types

Tags: c++, c

I was wondering what is the difference between `uint32_t` and `uint32`, and when I looked in the header files it had this:

```
types.h:

    /** @brief 32-bit unsigned integer. */
    typedef unsigned int uint32;
stdint.h:

    typedef unsigned   uint32_t;
```

This only leads to more questions:
What is the difference between

```
unsigned varName;
```

and

```
unsigned int varName;
```

?

I am using `MinGW.`

Comment: They're the same. However the type `uint32` (and the header `<types.h>` or the file `"types.h"`) is not defined by the C99 Standard. If you want to use one of those types, use `uint32_t` and include the header `<stdint.h>`. Also `unsigned` and `unsigned int` are the same.

Comment: So uint32 and <types.h> are not part of the standard, but uint32_t is?

Comment: @user1507133: Yes. Basically, there's no such thing as `uint32` neither in C nor in C++.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`unsigned` and `unsigned int` are synonymous, much like `unsigned short [int]` and `unsigned long [int]`.

`uint32_t` is a type that's (optionally) defined by the C standard. `uint32` is just a name you made up, although it happens to be defined as the same thing.

Comment: A bit of necromancy here, but comparing `unsigned [int]` to `[unsigned] (short|long) [int]` may give new programmers the false impression that `short` and `long` are unsigned by default.  I'd suggest `unsigned (short|long) [int]` instead.

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference.

`unsigned int = uint32 = uint32_t = unsigned` in your case and `unsigned int = unsigned` always

Comment: `unsigned int` == `unsigned`, but it is not in any way guaranteed that `uint32_t` == `unsigned int`. `unsigned int` can have any bit-width from 16 bit and up.

Comment: In an environment *with those particular typedefs*, `uint32_t` is by definition `unsigned int`.

Comment: @AndreyT: that's why I wrote "in your case"

Answer (score 4):

`unsigned` and `unsigned int` are synonymous for historical reasons; they both mean "unsigned integer of the most natural size for the CPU architecture/platform", which is often (but by no means always) 32 bits on modern platforms.

`<stdint.h>` is a standard header in C99 that is supposed to give type definitions for integers of particular sizes, with the `uint32_t` naming convention.

The `<types.h>` that you're looking at appears to be non-standard and presumably belongs to some framework your project is using. Its `uint32` typedef is compatible with `uint32_t`. Whether you should use one or the other in your code is a question for your manager.

Comment: "<stdint.h> is a standard header in C99".  What about C++98 and C++11?

Comment: `<cstdint>` is, I think, the equivalent C++ standard header.

Comment: @user1507133 - C++11 has <cstdint> which brings these types into the `std` namespace (e.g. `std::uint32_t`).  C++98 does not have this header because it predates C99.  POSIX provides `inttypes.h` with the same types if that is good enough.

Comment: According to the C Standard, `<inttypes.h>` includes `<stdint.h>`. So it "copies" every definition and provides a few extra ones (notably scanf and printf specifiers: `printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", x);`

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no difference between `unsigned` and `unsigned int`.

Whether that type is a good match for `uint32_t` is implementation-dependant though; an `int` could be "shorter" than 32 bits.