# Difference between uint32 and uint32_t

Tags: c++, c, uint32, uint32-t

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [Difference between different integer types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786113/difference-between-different-integer-types)

What is the difference between *uint32* and *uint32_t* in C/C++?

Are they OS-dependent?

In which case should I use one or another?

Comment: You should prefer Standard types wherever possible.  In this case, `uint32_t`.

Comment: guys. You can find answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786113/difference-between-different-integer-types

Comment: Out of curiosity - what is the "_t" meant to indicate?

Comment: Shorthand for "type".

Answer (score 126, accepted):

`uint32_t` is standard, `uint32` is not.  That is, if you include `<inttypes.h>` or `<stdint.h>`, you will get a definition of `uint32_t`.  `uint32` is a typedef in some local code base, but you should not expect it to exist unless you define it yourself.  And defining it yourself is a bad idea.

Comment: typedef uint32_t uint32?

Comment: If it doesn't exist, you won't be able to compile your program, right? Then you could do like Max suggested above. What's the big deal about it?

Comment: @Rodrigo  The "big deal" is the same as doing `#define writef printf`.  Technically, things will work just fine.  But it introduces unnecessary confusion.  And you'd be surprised how frequently you'll see simple typedefs like this morph over time until a code base has things like `typedef uint16_t uint32`, at which point the universe explodes.

Comment: Yes, I've dreamed of that already :)

Comment: Why is `typedef uint32_t uint32` bad? Surely the argument that someone shouldn't use a sensible typedef because someone could create an insane typedef is wrong. Eg we don't say pencils are evil since a crazy coworker could take a pencil and stab someone with it.

Answer (score 30):

`uint32_t` is defined in the standard, in

#### 18.4.1 Header `<cstdint>` synopsis [cstdint.syn]

```
namespace std {
//...
typedef unsigned integer type uint32_t; // optional
//...
}
```

`uint32` is not, it's a shortcut provided by some compilers (probably as `typedef uint32_t uint32`) for ease of use.

Comment: More likely as a typedef for something that was known to be an unsigned 32 bit integer at a time before `<cstdint>` was standard.

Comment: But how could an "unsigned integer of 32 bits" be any different?