# What is the difference between an Uint32 and an unsigned int in C++?

Tags: c++, types

Is it the same? If no: what is the difference?
If yes then why do you need this type?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786113/difference-between-different-integer-types

Answer (score 67, accepted):

`uint32_t` (or however pre-C++11 compilers call it) is guaranteed to be a 32-bit unsigned integer; `unsigned int` is whatever unsigned integer the compiler likes best to call `unsigned int`, as far as it meets the requirements of the standard (which demands for it a 0-65535 minimum range).

Like `int`, `unsigned int` typically is an integer that is fast to manipulate for the current architecture (normally it fits into a register), so it's to be used when a "normal", fast integer is required.

`uint32_t`, instead, is used when you need an exact-width integer, e.g. to serialize to file, or when you require that exact range or you rely on unsigned overflow to happen exactly at `2^32-1`.

For example, on a 16 bit-processor `unsigned int` will typically be 16 bits wide, while `uint32_t` will *have* to be 32 bits wide.

---

Incidentally, as pointed out by *@Marc Glisse*, while `unsigned int` is always present, `uint32_t` is not mandatory - a particular compiler implementation may not provide it. This is mostly because not all platforms can easily provide such a type (typically DSPs with weird word sizes).

Comment: Also, one is required to exist and not the other.

Comment: @user1511417: it makes no sense to ask which is better "a priori" - they both have their use, as outlined in the answer.

Comment: The `uint32_t` is also used when exact bit width access is needed, such as writing to hardware registers.

Comment: `uint_least32_t`, however, *is* required to exist. Doesn't help with direct hardware access, but does help with minimum width requirements.

Comment: "0-65535 minimum range" is a slight understatement. It must have a `[0, 2^N-1]` range with N >=16, in order to support modulo 2^N arithmetic.

Comment: @DevSolar Although `unsigned long int` is also guaranteed to be at least 32 bits wide and has been around forever.  I guess the least type would be useful on an implementation with something like 36-bit ints and `long` that’s wider.  You might want to use `least` for storage and `fast` for calculations there.

Comment: @Lorehead: Well, `unsigned long int` could be 64 bit as well, while `uint_least32_t` is also guaranteed that "no unsigned integer type with lesser size has at least the specified width". Plus, the `_t` type is explicit about its requirements, while `unsigned long` isn't. And I'd call 16 years of existence in the (C99) standard pretty much "forever" as well, even though I wrote C before that "forever".

Comment: @DevSolar Useful in comparison to `uint32_t`, which would exist basically everywhere except some really old mainframes that no one has ever written a C99 compiler for.  (Just like how `long` was 32 bits wide everywhere and also wide enough to hold a pointer or file offset, and neither of these assumptions would ever cause problems in the future.) But, you’re right, `uint_least32_t` and `uint_fast32_t` are the most future-proof types to use.